# the method is not applicable for the arguments ()

Tags: android

I'm trying to create an OnClick that will allow you to delete contacts but I have this error - "the method removeContact(Context, String) in the type ContactPickerTester is not applicable for the argument ()".

I am a very new programmer so I assume its something obvious that I am doing wrong.

```
Button deleteContactButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
        deleteContactButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                removeContact();
            }
        });
    }

                private void removeContact(Context context, String phone) {
                    //context.getContentResolver().delete(Contacts.Phones.CONTENT_URI, phone, null);
                    context.getContentResolver().delete(Contacts.Phones.CONTENT_URI,
                          Contacts.PhonesColumns.NUMBER+"=?", new String[] {phone});
                }
```

Comment: removeContact takes two parameters, the context and the phone number. You are not providing those, causing a compil time error

Comment: Derp... Thank you! One thing though, I want the onclick to open all contacts with the choice to delete given to the user. If values are given to phone number then it would just be deleting the number given, no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is located in the `OnClickListener` you have assigned to `deleteContactButton`.

Two parameters should be passed to `removeContact()` (the context and the phone number) and you have passed none, so the compile error:

```
Button deleteContactButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
    deleteContactButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            removeContact(); // <-- There should be two parameteres here
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm not sure what value they should be however, because I want the onClick to open up the contacts and allow the user to choose which to delete. Adding a phone value would mean just deleting said phone value, no?

Comment: Well, you should know, you are the guy who has implemented `removeContact()` :-) But looking at the code, yes, this is what would happen obviously. What you have to do now is to change the code of `removeContact()` in a way it would open the contact in a `Dialog`, for example, and propose to either delete it or cancel this action.